# Undefined variable post_id in custom quick edit coloumn

Tags: posts, variables, id, quick-edit

I am trying to add a custom coloumn to post quick edit and everything is almost working. Custom meta is saved and passed but if I click on quick edit the preview is blank.
This is the error it gives me:

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: **post_id** in /home/etimueit/public_html/wp-content/themes/caru/functions.php on line 626

[image: I can see the data here (last coloumn)]
[image: No variable here (but still saved in DB)]

Here is my code.

```
function disponibilitaet_quickedit_custom_posts_columns( $posts_columns ) {
    $posts_columns['disponibilitaet_edit_time'] = __( 'Modifica Disponibilit&agrave;', 'disponibilitaet' );
    return $posts_columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_post_posts_columns', 'disponibilitaet_quickedit_custom_posts_columns' );`

function disponibilitaet_quickedit_custom_column_display( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'disponibilitaet_edit_time' == $column_name ) {
        $dispo_registrata = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'disponibilitaet_edit_time', true );

        if ( $dispo_registrata ) {
            echo esc_html( $dispo_registrata );
        } else {
            esc_html_e( 'N/A', 'disponibilitaet' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_post_posts_custom_column', 'disponibilitaet_quickedit_custom_column_display', 10, 2 );

function disponibilitaet_quickedit_fields( $column_name, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'disponibilitaet_edit_time' != $column_name )
        return;`
    //This is line 626

    $dispo_registrata = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'disponibilitaet_edit_time', true );
    ?>
    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right">
        <div class="inline-edit-col">
            <label>
                <span class="title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Disponibilit&agrave;', 'disponibilitaet' ); ?></span>
                <span class="input-text-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="disponibilitaet_edit_time" class="disponibilitaetedittime" value="<?php echo $dispo_registrata;?>">
            </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'quick_edit_custom_box', 'disponibilitaet_quickedit_fields', 10, 2 );

function disponibilitaet_quickedit_save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
    // if called by autosave, then bail here
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // if this "post" post type?
    if ( $post->post_type != 'post' )
        return;

    // does this user have permissions?
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    // update!
    if ( isset( $_POST['disponibilitaet_edit_time'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'disponibilitaet_edit_time', $_POST['disponibilitaet_edit_time'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'disponibilitaet_quickedit_save_post', 10, 2 );

function disponibilitaet_quickedit_javascript() {
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $current_screen->id != 'edit-post' || $current_screen->post_type != 'post' )
        return;

    // Ensure jQuery library loads
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            $( '#the-list' ).on( 'click', 'a.editinline', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var editTime = $(this).data( 'edit-time' );
                inlineEditPost.revert();
                $( '.disponibilitaetedittime' ).val( editTime ? editTime : '' );
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts-edit.php', 'disponibilitaet_quickedit_javascript' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are, finally found a solution, I leave it here so maybe it can help (maybe also future me XD ).

```
/**
```

*
 * Aggiungi Disponibilità nel Quick Edit
*/

```
function etdispo_quickedit_custom_posts_columns( $posts_columns ) {
    $posts_columns['et2018-quantita_birra'] = __( 'Disponibilità', 'etdispo' );
    return $posts_columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_post_posts_columns', 'etdispo_quickedit_custom_posts_columns' );

function etdispo_quickedit_custom_column_display( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'et2018-quantita_birra' == $column_name ) {
        $etdispo_regi = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'et2018-quantita_birra', true );

        if ( $etdispo_regi ) {
            echo esc_html( $etdispo_regi );
        } else {
            esc_html_e( 'N/A', 'etdispo' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_post_posts_custom_column', 'etdispo_quickedit_custom_column_display', 10, 2 );

function etdispo_quickedit_fields( $column_name, $post_type, $post_id ) {
    if ( 'et2018-quantita_birra' != $column_name )
        return;

    $etdispo_regi = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'et2018-quantita_birra', true );
    ?>
    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right">
        <div class="inline-edit-col">
            <label>
                <span class="title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Disponibilità', 'etdispo' ); ?></span>
                <span class="input-text-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="et2018-quantita_birra" class="etdispoedit" value="">
            </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'quick_edit_custom_box', 'etdispo_quickedit_fields', 10, 3 );
function etdispo_quickedit_save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
    // if called by autosave, then bail here
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // if this "post" post type?
    if ( $post->post_type != 'post' )
        return;

    // does this user have permissions?
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    // update!
    if ( isset( $_POST['et2018-quantita_birra'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'et2018-quantita_birra', $_POST['et2018-quantita_birra'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'etdispo_quickedit_save_post', 10, 2 );

function etdispo_quickedit_javascript() {
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $current_screen->id != 'edit-post' || $current_screen->post_type != 'post' )
        return;

    // Ensure jQuery library loads
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            $( '#the-list' ).on( 'click', 'a.editinline', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var editDispo = $(this).data( 'edit-dispo' );
                inlineEditPost.revert();
                $( '.etdispoedit' ).val( editDispo ? editDispo : '' );
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts-edit.php', 'etdispo_quickedit_javascript' );
/* Qui */
function etdispo_quickedit_set_data( $actions, $post ) {
    $found_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'et2018-quantita_birra', true );

    if ( $found_value ) {
        if ( isset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] ) ) {
            $new_attribute = sprintf( 'data-edit-dispo="%s"', esc_attr( $found_value ) );
            $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] = str_replace( 'class=', "$new_attribute class=", $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
        }
    }

    return $actions;
}
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'etdispo_quickedit_set_data', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I've had to change my answer after checking the WordPress Codex on adding custom editable data to the quick edit. So you'll have to remove the references to `$post_id` too (from the `add_action` arguments and from within your function).

It looks like the `quick_edit_custom_box` only takes 2 arguments: `$column_name` and `$post_type`. Then for getting and displaying the value, this has to be done using some more PHP and Javascript.

If you read further in to the WordPress Codex on the [quick edit custom box](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/quick_edit_custom_box) and read further down to the section on '[Setting Existing Values](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/quick_edit_custom_box#Setting_Existing_Values)', you'll see there's a fair bit more work required in order to do this.

I'd suggest reading the docs in a bit more detail as it's not quite as straight-forward as I first thought...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the error is gone with the field :)
https://imgur.com/a/n1z45
Is there a way to also show the field in Quick Edit?

Comment: I've just changed my answer as I've just read the documentation and it looks like there's a fair bit more work involved in doing this and it's not as I first thought...